# USB-C to USB Type A Gen 2 adapter, do they exist?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-c

After much searching, I can only find USB-C to USB Type A Gen 1, do Gen 2 versions exist?

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B017W3J65M/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2K1DKKHECCS2U&psc=1

Comment: Yes;  They absolutely exist.  Most USB 3.1 Gen 2 and USB 3.2 Gen 2, and USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 cables actually are Type-C.

Comment: Thanks, but thats my issue. I have a USB Type A Gen 2 device that I want to connect to my thunderbolt port.

Comment: Thunderbolt != USB Type-C;  Why don't you just purchase a [Type-C Thunderbolt cable](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Thunderbolt-Type-C-Cable-F2CD081bt1M-BLK/dp/B01CEFESRO)?  [There exists Type-A to Type-C Gen 2 adapters.](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07M981YYR/?coliid=IAP9TH2F2JX9&colid=ALLGFUJQ23QF&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it)

Comment: Question seeking hardware recommendations are not within scope

Comment: My computer supports thunderbolt using the USB-C connector. The port supports Gen 2 speed, so I want to connect my USB Type A gen 2 device to the USB-C/Thunderbolt port. Your link is the other way around. I am looking for a gen2 version of the link I originally included. My search reveals none, which makes me wonder why!

Comment: If you’re worried about speed loss, you might want to use an adapter cable instead, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By connectivity/schematics, USB-C to USB-A adapters have no differences for Gen1 and Gen2 speed rates. The difference is only in insertion loss of signal, which is determined by quality of PCB interposer. Cables can be bad in this sense, but if you choose a "cabless" variant of this kind of adapters (short adapter), like this one or similar, shorter is better:
[image]
it will very likely work just fine for Gen2 speeds. I have one that works perfectly fine at 10 Gbps. Your mileage may vary, you might need to purchase several different brands/makes and check them out.

ADDITION: more directed search shows this one, apparently qualified for 10Gbps speed:
[image]